# Set the first page is double page instead of single page in turn.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
    Views
A view is a set of pages that are visible on the screen; in general 
that moment depends on the current page.  For example, when the 
display of a flipbook of 10 pages is set to double, the pages would 
be grouped like this:
1
2-3
4-5
6-7
8-9
10
```

From the offical document, the first page is single page and display on the right hand side.Is it possible to change it to double page?
Like:

1-2

2-3

4-5

5-6

6-7

....

Would any developer experience in turn.js can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the example fiddle they provide on [How Turn.js Works](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/How_Turn.js_Works) I removed the 2nd `div class="hard"` which results in the title page followed by both page 1 and 2 visible. Here's that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_nauman/EBUZ2/).

If you don't even want a title page you can open the book directly to pages 1 and 2 as seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_nauman/c8nNh/).

Have a look at issues [138](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/138), [195](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/195), and [45](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/45) for more info.

Comment: Sorry for the last question , is it possible to make an invisible page?

Comment: eg. I restrict the page number to 6 , and the first page is invisble, the second page is the cover page

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean by restrict the page number to 6? When the second page is the cover page is it displayed by itself or along with page 3?

Comment: This solution does not open pages like 1-2 (or fake page title & 1) but 2-3. I would like also to have opened the cover with page #1.